# The Gemara teaches the concept that שומר מצוה לא ידע דבר רע. I have a question on that concept

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, genesis-bereishith

If a person who is observing a mitzvah will not be harmed, how is it possible that Hevel was murdered as a result of the Korban he offered?

Comment: Didn't Kohelet teach that concept first?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. You don’t tell us where the Gemara teaches this.  If you provide that information (by [edit]ing the question) it may help people find an answer (e.g. by checking the commentaries on that Gemara).

Answer (score 2):

In the sefer Asicha Rav Chaim kanievsky answered because Hevel wasn't commanded in bringing a korban therefore he wasn't protected.
It's brought from Maharal (there in side notes) that Hevel wasn't protected because he was influenced by someone else to do the mitzva. (In this case kayin). A mitzva only protects when you enlight yourself to do the mitzva.

Comment: There are those that prove from Yehuda and Tamar (this week's parsha) that שומר מצות לא ידע דבר רע doesn't apply to a Katlanis, otherwise they would have done Yibum. According to this answer, there's no proof because Yehuda and his family weren't commanded in Yibum. Although, there is a Midrash that says Yehudah **was** commanded to have his family fulfill the *mitzvah* of Yibum, so then I guess Rav Chaim would say those commentaries would assume like this Midrash.

Comment: @robev.. chavtzalas hasharon reid on this... from Chasam Sofer that by katan there's chashash he's a sris and won't get a mitzva. So by katlanis would be machmir...so have to wait untill gadol to see if he's sris...

Comment: Right...again assuming it doesn't matter if he's metzuveh or not. I'm not arguing on Rav Chaim I'm just pointing out many authorities don't assume this, unless we limit what they hold

Comment: @robev The *yavam* can't be better than the *mes* since he is only *ba mikocho*, so this is not a proof for a general principle?

Comment: @robev We know why they were killed. If two die in a car accident she is not a katlanis.

Comment: Let's be honest to ourselves. We all know people like Hevel, who died doing the right thing. Think about it... How could Roi Klein Hy"d have died jumping on a grenade to save his unit? Even if he hadn't died saying Shema he still was oseiq bemitzvah! But that's a different Mi Yodea question... (One I think I answered in the past.)

Comment: @interested as far as Yehuda was concerned she was deemed a katlanis

Comment: @micha berger yes the principle isn't said if it's shciach hezeika. That's the whole shaila if you apply the concept to yibum to a katlanis..

Comment: @Shlomy: and you've only seen exceptions in dangerous situations? The problem is more complex than that, but it's a MY question in and of itself...

Comment: @micha berger chazal say one who does a mitzva is protected...  when we see it's not always true it's a difficulty that needs to be addressed. Thus the above mentioned question. Answering by saying i have more difficulties isn't an answer.

Comment: @Shlomy, I said "that's a different Mi Yodea question". So, I created a Q&A to give my opinion on the subject. If you have a different approach, you can give it there. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118975/1570